# Adodb.GetRow() not returning data when there is a Insert before a Select in the query

Tags: php, sql-server, select, procedure, adodb

I'm new. Most of the times I find solutions here just by reading but now I have to ask you directly because of the weirdness of my subject.

I have an application in php and I used to use the mssql libraries to connect to MS Server 2008 but now I migrated part of my code to connect through ADODB http://adodb.sourceforge.net/

I have a store procedure which I use to validate/insert/update/delete rows depending of parameters I send, so at the very bottom I have a line of code like this

```
 Select @Result Result
```

This variable just tell me everytime if the proccess went correctly or if I'm missing something so the row doesn't get inserted/deleted/updated.

Here the code of my store procedure

```
        create procedure sp_MyTable @id int, @name varchar(100), @type varchar(10)
        as

        declare @Results varchar(100)
         set @Result=@type
         --validations!
        if exists(select * from MyTable where name=@name)begin

        set @Result='No insert:('
        end

         if @Result='insert'           
          insert into MyTable (name)values(@name)


           select @Result Result
```

Here and example of code to create my connection in php

```
        $pQry='exec sp_MyTable @id="0",@name="Hello",@type="insert"';


            require ("php/ExtClases/adodb5/adodb.inc.php");

             $db = ADONewConnection('mssqlnative');
             $db->debug = false;

             $db->Connect($datCon['sServer'], $datCon['UID'], $datCon['PWD'], $datCon['Database']);

            $ADODB_FETCH_MODE = ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC;

            $rs = $db->Execute($pQry);          

            $rows=$rs->GetRows();
```

So, it is supposed to return and Array like this

```
 print_r($rows);
 //Array ([0]=>Array( [Result] => insert )) )
```

But It prints just nothing.

Using Management Studio I already ran this procedure directly on my own computer and at the server online  and both cases retrieved data, so the store procedure is fine.

If I remove the insert statement:

```
        create procedure sp_MyTable @id int, @name varchar(100), @type varchar(10)
        as

        declare @Results varchar(100)
         set @Result=@type
         --validations!
        if exists(select * from MyTable where name=@name)begin

        set @Result='No insert:('
        end

        /*
           No insert!
         */


           select @Result Result
```

It works!.

```
          print_r($rows);
          //Array ([0]=>Array( [Result] => insert)) )
```

_*UPDATE: even if I print something (print 'something') in the store procedure ADODB ignores the select statement, so the select must be totally alone.
I think I will consider searching for another way.
_*.

PD: Sorry for my bad english.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it took a few hours of my appreciated life but at last now I know what is going on.

**MSSQL** driver use to ignore all but the last statement (as I remember...). So, if you have something like this

```
    $query="select * from table1; select some, data from table2; select yadda yadda from table3";

    $conn=mysql_connect($sServer,$UID,$PWD);
    $baseDatos=mysql_select_db($Database,$conn);
    $res=mysql_query($query);

        While($row=mssql_fetch_array($res)){
            print($row);
        }
```

You will have printed the results only of **table3**.
( **ACTUALLY** Here it is written that you can have multiple recorset and navigate through them with mssql http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mssql-next-result.php but at the moment I don't know why it takes just the **last one as the first one**. Maybe it doesn't recognize prints or inserts as recorsets at all)

**ADODB** library actually uses **SQLSRV** to handle connections and queries to any sql server (mssqlnative). SQLSRV is the official driver  released for Microsoft so is slightly different. You need to  use the function sqlsrv_next_result or it will be return just the **first** result whatever it is (print,insert,select,etc)

here the link
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-next-result.php
and another guy who had the same problem
[SQLSRV and multiple selects in Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169124/sqlsrv-and-multiple-selects-in-stored-procedure)

what I did is not pretty but with patience I think I can fix it in the future, for now I just need the last recorset (table3) and not the first, so ...

```
    /*here my temporary fix*/
        do {
        $result = array();
           while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($this->_queryID)) {
               $result[] = $row;
           }
        } while (!is_null(sqlsrv_next_result($this->_queryID)));

        return $result;
              /**/
```

I overwrite the variable $result with every step into the results :). Funny code.

Cheers